# UTF-8 Encoding Character set

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I'm working on an e-mail app for fun and practice in Ruby and one of the mails has this subject:

```
=?UTF-8?B?4p22IEFuZHJvaWQgc3RpY2sgbWsgODA5aXYgKyB1c2IyZXRoZXJuZXQgYWRh?=\r\n
      =?UTF-8?B?cHRlciAtNDYlIOKdtyBKb3NlcGggSm9zZXBoIGtldWtlbmNhcnJvdXNlbCAt?=\r\n
      =?UTF-8?B?NTUlIOKduCA0IENlcnJ1dGkgYm94ZXJzaG9ydHMgLTcxJSDinbkgQXJub3Zh?=\r\n
      =?UTF-8?B?IDkwIEc0IHRhYmxldCAtNDIl?=
```

I found out I look at a Base64 string and the parts between `=?UTF-8?B?` and `?=` need to be decoded from Base64 to UTF-8.

Can someone explain how I need to decode a string like this in Ruby?

Comment: What is the encryption technique used to encrypt the data ?

Comment: I don't know, this is just the subject of a mail I've received.. Can I get the encryption information out of the header of this mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `Base64` module of [ruby-1.9](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9) [stdlib](/questions/tagged/stdlib), see example:

```
require "base64"

enc   = Base64.encode64('Send reinforcements')
                # -> "U2VuZCByZWluZm9yY2VtZW50cw==\n"
plain = Base64.decode64(enc)
                # -> "Send reinforcements"
```

Since the `=?UTF-8?B?` is set the proper [codepage](/questions/tagged/codepage) or encoding, in which the original string was coded, it is required to be present in email messages. I believe strings without the defined codepage are defaulted to [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8)

Comment: Thanks, this will get me further! What about the `=?UTF-8?B?`, is it practical to read this to use the correct decoding, or can i just strip it with a regex?

Comment: Great! I didn't find any encoding info in the headers, but used this regex `scan(/\=?UTF-8\?B\?([^"]*)\?=/)` to get the part in between, it creates a string in 2 arrays (?).